# My php code is not being executed

Tags: php, pages, cookies

I have a wordpress page that has this code in the text editor part of a web page:

```
This page creates a cookie and houses a etst link that is only accessible to the holder of the cookie.

&nbsp;
Test Link (authentication required).
&nbsp;
Syntax:
<span style="color: #444444;">setcookie(name, value, expire, path, domain);</span>
<?php setcookie(accesscookie, testing1234, time()+86400, /, foo.example.com); ?>
```

When I navigate to the page it does not create a new cookie.
Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong to create the cookie?

Comment: @Elliot_Labs, please use stackoverflow.com for these type of questions. This is not a wordpress questions, but a php question.

Comment: Sorry. Will do in the future :)

Comment: @gdaniel I looked at another semi similar question on stackoverflow.com and they moved it to wordpress.stackexchange.com for the same erason that you want to move it over there.

Comment: By 'text editor part of a webpage", do you mean in the text editor in WordPress admin? You can't execute PHP in the WordPress editor without a plugin or function in functions.php that specifically allows PHP execution. It's for security.

Comment: By text editor I mean that I clicked the text tab on the page/post editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out how to make a cookie system per-page and not on a site wide setup:
I setup a java script section in my webpage to create the cookie (the text editor).
Here is the code that I used:

```
<script type=”text/javascript”>
<!–
document.cookie=”AuthCookie=OpenSesame; Domain=example.com; path=/”;
//–></script>
```

Hope this helps somebody out who does not want a site wide cookie creation setup :)

Thanks to: @Edd Smith his help and guidance. 
I eventually looked into alternative wasy to make a cookie and found some documentation at W3Schools.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to set a cookie after the headers have already been sent.

You need to set you cookies at the top of the header template before the doc type deceleration.

Comment: This needs to be a per-page solution not a site wide solution.

Comment: Would some kind of if statement based upon URL do the trick?

Comment: I need the system to make a cookie so that when the user clicks on the test link an htaccess file check for the cookie and allows access. Basically I am going from WordPress to html files and I need them to be protected.

Comment: Ok - what's the end goal, what are you trying to achieve with this code? A secured page?

Comment: A secured set of pages from an index page (which creates the cookie) also any subdirectories that it may or may not have and any files in those:
www.example.com/list - This is in WordPress
www.example.com/page1.html - An html file
www.example.com/page2.html - Another HTML file
www.example.com/page3.html - HTML file

Comment: Do the users have to be logged in, do they have a user group associated with them? Or is it only one user to one page?

Comment: It is like this: The user has to be logged into WordPress and visit the page. After clicking the link they have the WordPress logged-in cookie checked and also the cookie that we have just created. If both of them are present then they can access the content.

Comment: How about if you make the link the user has to click a trigger a hidden form? When the user clicks the link, post to a form processor, pass through the data you need in hidden inputs and set the cookie in there. Then exit the script and redirect it back to whatever page you want?

Comment: I am not that advanced. Could you give me an example?

Comment: Alternatively another technique I have used for allowing specific users access to Wordpress pages. Is creating a custom meta box on a post type. Then entering in there a list of user names that can access the page. Then if statements on the front end do the rest of the work if the current user is not on the allowed user list.

Comment: I do not want to have to touch it after it is set up. That is what is currently in place (or something similar: .htpasswd and .htaccess). Remember that WordPress is only linking to a hand coded html system. I wanted htaccess to do the authentication somehow.

Comment: Users would create a WordPress account and get a subscription. That would allow it to the link page that is supposed to make a cookie. they click on the link and htaccess would verify the cookies and allow or deny access.

Comment: I have manually created the cookies and the htaccess works. Now it is just to implementing the cookie creation for the second cookie and getting the htaccess to require BOTH cookies...

Comment: Set the second cookie set with a form. Not at my computer right now to hack together a demo. First work out how to create a form and send it to a PHP processor. Then all you have to do is set your cookie in there like you are currently doing.

Comment: OK I will look into it:"PHP form cookie creation" to Google

Comment: I am not finding anything on that search. Could you define form? All I am getting is how to code a contact form without a plugin.

Comment: Any updates on the examples?

Comment: Hello? You still trying to get an example together?